# Why malloc returns 2 * sizeof(size_t) aligned memory in x86_64 system?

Tags: c, malloc, glibc

In the `GNU` implementation of  `malloc()` it is said that **Alignment: 2 * sizeof(size_t) (default)**.

Why 2 * sizeof(size_t) needed ?

size_t is used to keep track of the `chunk size`. The `sizeof(size_t)`generally is 8 bytes (they can set to be of 4 bytes) and pointers are 8 bytes in x86_64 system, so according to alignment rule, alignment of 8 bytes will work. Why alignment of 16 bytes is needed ?

Comment: First, the properties of `malloc` are not determined by whether the target is an x86_64 system. There are multiple C implementations on x86_64 systems, including multiple implementations by Apple, multiple implementations by Microsoft, and multiple implementations by open-source software. The implementors of each implementation may decide for themselves how `malloc` behaves within the limits of the C standard (if the implementors choose to conform to the C standard, which is not required).

Comment: Second, the minimum alignment that `malloc` provides is chosen for various reasons. The implementation may have a fundamental type that requires 16-byte alignment. Or it may be desired that all memory provided by `malloc` be suitable for efficient use with the processor’s SIMD features (such as SSE), which may require or benefit from 16-byte alignment, depending on the processor model. Or it may be decided that the minimum size `malloc` should provide should be at least 16 bytes, even if fewer bytes are requested, because there is some internal overhead to `malloc` and/or…

Comment: … the internal data structures it uses motivate using at least 16 bytes per allocation, and, once each allocation is at least 16-bytes, they are all naturally 16-byte aligned, because memory has been essentially divided up into 16-byte chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, `_Float128` is a basic type (an implementation-defined floating type).  `_Float128` requires 128-bit alignment, so the fundamental alignment is at least 16, and all pointers returned by `malloc` have to meet that alignment requirement.

Not all `malloc` implementations respect the fundamental alignment for allocations smaller than 16 bytes, though.